# How to get a variable image in richfaces from resources

Tags: image, jsf, richfaces, el

I have a problem showing images on my page:

```
<h:graphicImage value="resource:///image/actors/#{imageBean.source}" alt="pic" />
```

where the result of **#{imageBean.source} = "image.jpg"**

result:

> [13:10:14.445] GET http ://localhost:7001/webapp-core/faces/image.jpg
>   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 578ms]

Doesn't obviously work, but i dont know what the correct way would be.

I have tried many variations, f.e.:

```
- <h:graphicImage value="#{resource['image/actors/imageBean.source']}" alt="pic" />
- <h:graphicImage value="resource:///#{imageBean.source}" alt="pic" />
- <h:graphicImage value="#{resource['image/akteurs/imageBean.source']}" alt="pic" />
```

My main problem is how to get #{imageBean} working inside the resource context.

The correct path is:

> [13:37:28.935] GET
>   http: //localhost:7001/webapp-core/faces/**javax.faces.resource**/image/actors/image.jpg
>   [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 31ms]

settings web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resource://` URI is not valid in this context. It has an entirely different purpose. To reference JSF resources in the view, you should be using `#{resource}`.

---

> *My main problem is how to get #{imageBean} working inside the resource context.*

You can just inline it by creating another string variable in EL beforehand using JSTL [`<c:if>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/c/if.html):

```
<c:set var="identifier" value="image/actors/#{imageBean.source}" />
<h:graphicImage value="#{resource[identifier]}" alt="pic" />
```

Or, if your environment supports EL 2.2, make use of [`String#concat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29):

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{resource['image/actors/'.concat(imageBean.source)]}" alt="pic" />
```

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know about the EL before JSTL